# FCMP with VARARGS not working as expected?

Tags: sas, fcmp

While researching FCMP to help answer another question on here, I was left a bit perplexed by how `proc fcmp` works when using the `VARARGS` option in order to be able to call that function with a variable number of arguments. [The sas support page for the FUNCTION statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002975331.htm) provides the following example and clearly states that *"the example implies that the summation function can be called as follows: sum = summation(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);."*

```
options cmplib=sasuser.funcs;

proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.funcs.temp;
function summation (b[*]) varargs;
    total = 0;
    do i = 1 to dim(b);
        total = total + b[i];
    end;
return(total);
endsub;
sum=summation(1,2,3,4,5);
   put sum=;
run;
```

Running this seems to work well and produces an output report showing `sum=15` which seems to indicate that calling the function as `summation(1,2,3,4,5)` works as expected.

However, if I then try to use that function in the same way in a data step

```
data _null_;
test=summation(1,2,3,4,5);
run;
```

I get errors in the log

> ERROR 72-185: The summation function call has too many arguments.
>
> ERROR 707-185: Expecting array for argument 1 of the summation subroutine call.

This has me confused. Am I missing something obvious?

The second error message says that the function is expecting an array as argument 1. Forgetting the fact that calling the function that way in the `fcmp` proc seemed to work and that the SAS support seems to indicate that this is the whole point of this; expecting an array, which can indeed be of varying length, is really not the same as accepting a variable number of arguments, an array being one argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you specify VARARGS, then the last argument in the function must be an array.

And later on:

> Note: When calling this function from a DATA step, you must provide the VARARGS as an array.

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n10vesidziklh1n1l7kidq4dqd0r.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Please make sure to use the latest version of the documentation, in this case 9.4. Unless you happen to unfortunately be stuck on version 9.2.
This works for me - note that it's not how I expected it to work as well...but it does :).

```
data demo;
    array test(4) (1, 2, 3, 4);
    check = summation(test);
    put check=;
run;
```

Comment: All right, fair enough. The doc for 9.4 provides [the same example](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p0f3ukbprxtdfrn1cljibie17wzn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p0f3ukbprxtdfrn1cljibie17wzn) as the 9.2 doc with the added note about usage in the data step. I still seems pretty stupid/useless though. What's the point of providing a way to define a function that takes a variable number of arguments but that can only be used as such within the very `proc fcmp` where it is defined?

Comment: @user2877959 - agreed it is strange that you can get away with the 'variable number of arguments' within `proc fcmp` itself, I'd always thought you had to provide an array variable.   Variable arguments in fcmp would be super useful.

Comment: @user2877959 I didn't say I agreed with it, just that's how it works. If you want to suggest a change, I would check the SAS Ballot Ideas and add it on, if its not already there.This is the closest one I found but isn't exactly your question. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/An-issue-with-use-of-user-defined-function-created-by-PROC-FCMP/idi-p/219754

Answer (score 1):

Just clarifying based on your comment "What's the point of providing a way to define a function that takes a variable number of arguments but that can only be used as such within the very proc fcmp where it is defined?".

FCMP can load the function either using the inlib= proc option or option CMPLIB.  Since FCMP knows how to call a varargs function you can still use the option, just from other proc fcmp steps or fcmp functions.